# Trouble converting strings into floats

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

pandas version 0.13

### dummy dataframe

```
d = {'one':['97628', '97628', '97628.271', '97628271'],  
     'two':['98800', '98800', '98800.000', '98800000']}

a = pd.DataFrame(d)  
a
```

[image]

```
a.dtypes
```

one    object
two    object
dtype: object

Everything looks good up to this point. I then try to convert the strings into floats.

```
a.loc[:,'one'] = a.loc[:,'one'].astype(float)  
a.loc[:,'two'] = a.loc[:,'two'].astype(float)
```

Nothing changes after I execute the code.

```
a.dtypes
```

one    object
two    object
dtype: object

The worst part is that the data in the dataframe has changed

[image]

Is this a bug or am I changing the data types incorrectly?

Comment: FYI, your method of using ``loc`` to convert doesn't work because pandas doesn't check whether the entire column is converted (as you could have done something like ``df.loc[1:5,'one'] = df.loc[:,'one'].astype(float)``, so for efficiency we don't force this type of conversion. you could have done ``df['one'] = df['one'].astype(float)`` which would have worked (but @AndyHayden soln is in general better for float conversion in any event; ``astype(float)`` would fail if their was a non-convertible entry (e.g. a 'foo') in your data).

Comment: I originally used df['one'] but it did not work so I went and tried "loc". I did retry and everything worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What's happening here is the conversion is happening correctly:

```
In [21]: a.loc[:,'one'].astype(float)
Out[21]: 
0       97628.000
1       97628.000
2       97628.271
3    97628271.000
Name: one, dtype: float64
```

*but it's being **assigned** to an object column (what you're seeing is formatting is simply number formatting - the numbers are correct).*

A nice way to do this is to use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html):

```
In [11]: a.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[11]: 
            one       two
0     97628.000     98800
1     97628.000     98800
2     97628.271     98800
3  97628271.000  98800000

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [12]: a.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
Out[12]: 
one    float64
two    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I did try this method but I was getting NaN on a different dataset and this is the reason I eventually did not go this route. Thanks.

Comment: @DataByDavid you can just assign to the *entire* column: a['one'] = a.loc[:,'one'].astype(float)